# Given two objects, how can I update one objects properties based on another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to match update an object's property based on another object's property. The property names must match. A very simple example of what I am trying to achieve would look like this:

Given two objects:

```
var obj1 = {
   one: "1",
   two: "2",
   three: {
            threeDotOne: "3.1",
            threeDotTwo: "3.2",
            threeDotAny: "3.3"
          }
}

var obj2 = {threeDotAny: "3.4"}
```

updateObjectOneProperty(obj1, obj2)

and the result would look like this:

```
var obj1 = {
   one: "1",
   two: "2",
   three: {
            threeDotOne: "3.1",
            threeDotTwo: "3.2",
            threeDotAny: "3.4"
          }
}
```

Here I am assuming that there will only be ONE property with such a name in obj1, which is fine.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: [What have you tried to do in code?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I don't think there's a lib for that.

Comment: If `obj2` was instead `{ three: { threeDotAny: "3.4"} }`, you could simply use `$.extend( obj1, obj2, true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `$.extend` can do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/vjCvM/

```
var obj1 = {
    one: "1",
    two: "2",
    three: {
        threeDotOne: "3.1",
        threeDotTwo: "3.2",
        threeDotAny: "3.3"
    }
}

var obj2 = {
    threeDotAny: "3.4"
}

$.extend(obj1.three, obj2);
```

If you wanted to be able to do it without specifying `obj1.three`, `three` would need to be a property of `obj2` otherwise there's no way of knowing where to put it.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Is there a way I could call a recursive function and go through each child and possibly make a call like $.extend(child, obj2) ?

Comment: No because there's no way of knowing that `obj2` should go in `one`, `two`, or `three` of obj1. If obj2 matched obj1, then yes you would just add a third parameter to $.extend set to true like in my comment.

Comment: Hmmm what I am trying to say is something like this:

function updateObjectOneProperty(obj1, obj2)
{
    for(var key1 in obj1) // something that iterates through each prop
                         // of obj1
    { 
        for (var key2 obj2)
        {

    }
}

Comment: That's what `$.extend` does.

Comment: Sorry hit enter key by mistake without finishing...
Hmmm what I am trying to say is something like this:

    function updateObjectOneProperty(obj1, obj2)
    {
        for(var key1 in obj1)//each prop of obj1
       { 
            for (var key2 obj2)
            {
                 if(key1 == key2)
                 {
                      $.extend(key1, key2); 
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     updateObjectOneProperty(key1, obj2);
                 }
            }

        }
    }

Does this make sense ?

Comment: no that doesn't make sense. I don't follow what you are trying to say/do.